# Simultaneously flipping two values in a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy array such as:

```
[0,1,0,2,2]
```

and I'd like to simultaneously flip the 0s and 2s in the list (to get `[2,1,2,0,0]`), what would be the best way?

Comment: Are the only values in the array 0, 1 or 2?

Comment: yup, but i'd like a solution that's adaptable to more varied arrays as well if poss..

Comment: For your example array you could simply compute `2 - x`, where `x` is your array. There may be other shortcuts available depending on what exactly you mean by "more varied arrays".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of conditionals in numpy.

```
def switchvals(arr, val1, val2):
    mask1 = arr == val1
    mask2 = arr == val2
    arr[mask1] = val2
    arr[mask2] = val1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple function to do this. You pass it the two numbers and the matrix you want the numbers flipped in, and it returns the new matrix.

```
    def flip(a,b,mat):
        NewMat=np.array(size(mat))
        for entry in range(len(mat)):
            if mat[entry]==a:
                NewMat[entry]=b
            else if mat[entry]==b:
                NewMat[entry]=a
            else:
                NewMat[entry]=mat[entry]
        return NewMat
```

Comment: Since we're dealing with numpy arrays, boolean indexing will probably be much faster than a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

You could do some additions with the input array to have the desired effect, as listed in the code below -

```
def flip_vals(A,val1,val2):

    # Find the difference between two values
    diff = val2 - val1

    # Scale masked portion of A based upon the difference value in positive 
    # and negative directions and add up with A to have the desired output
    return A + diff*(A==val1) - diff*(A==val2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [49]: A = np.random.randint(0,8,(4,5))

In [50]: A
Out[50]: 
array([[0, 2, 3, 0, 3],
       [1, 5, 6, 6, 3],
       [1, 6, 7, 6, 4],
       [3, 7, 0, 3, 7]])

In [51]: flip_vals(A,3,6)
Out[51]: 
array([[0, 2, 6, 0, 6],
       [1, 5, 3, 3, 6],
       [1, 3, 7, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 0, 6, 7]])
```

If by best, you meant performance wise, I would go with the other `logical indexing` based solution.